# Intel nextbook downgrade

Tags: windows, windows-10

I have an Intel nextbook 2 in 1 from Walmart that came with Windows 8 32bit and I upgraded to Windows 10 and I'm wondering if I can downgrade to Windows 7. I have made a bootable USB of Windows 7 that boots on my Lenovo IdeaPad 10 but won't boot on my nextbook. I have edited the bios already and was even able to dual boot Android on it and Kali Linux but cat get Windows 7 to boot on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am afraid that thing will be hard.

Intel nextbook 2 in 1 is a portable Tablet PC, which has touchscreen and use tablet mode system, Windows 8.1 and Windows 10 have tablet mode can be used for tablet, but Windows 7 doesn’t support this feature.

Therefore, I think Windows 7 is not compatible with your nextbook. Maybe you could try to in-place install Windows 7 via iso, take a chance.

Download Windows 7 Disc Images (ISO Files)

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows7

Comment: +1. Besides touchscreen, there can be plenty of other components for which no driver is available for Windows 7

Comment: Ok thanks I had also tried running the setup file inside the bootable USB while still in Windows 10 and it stops at expanding files then it tells me it couldn't prepare Windows to boot to the next phase